# Writing a class for books in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, instance-variables

I'm writing a class in Python that keeps track of a selection of books. There are three instance variables: `author`, `title`, and `book_id`. There are four methods:

1. `__init__(self, author, title, book_id)`: (constructor; instantiates all instance variables.)
2. `__str__(self)`: returns string representation with this format 
   `Book("Homer", "The Odyssey", 12345)`
3. `__repr__(self)`: returns same string representation as `__str__`
4. `__eq__(self,    other)` determines if book itself is equivalent to the other book by checking if all three instance variables are the same. Returns a `bool`.

I've reached a road block. Here is the code I have so far I have gotten a good start. For some reason I keep getting indent errors with the return for the `__repr__` method. If anyone familiar with writing classes has any advice I'd appreciate it.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, author, title, book_id):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
        self.book_id = book_id

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Book(author, title, book_id)'

    def __repr__(self):

        return 'Book(author, title, book_id)'

    def __eq__(self, other):

    #Not sure if this is the right approach

        for title in Book:
            for title in Book:
                if title == title:
                    if author == author:
                        if book_id == book_id:
                            return True
```

Comment: You've mixed tabs and spaces for indentation. Stop doing that. (Your `__eq__` is also thoroughly wrong, but the tabs and spaces are what's causing the problem you're asking about.)

Comment: Also, your `__str__` is redundant, and both your `__str__` and `__repr__` are returning the literal string `'Book(author, title, book_id)'` instead of substituting the attribute values you want.

Comment: a Book is not iterable. `for title in Book` is not right. You need to reference `self.title == other.title and self.author == other.author`, for example

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone Imiguelvargasf's answer seems to fix these problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are not implementing well the method `__eq__`. Second you are not, returning the data you have in your book, but just a string `'Book(author, title, book_id)'`. I hope this solves your problem.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, author, title, book_id):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
        self.book_id = book_id

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Book({}, {}, {})'.format(self.author, self.title, self.book_id)

    def __repr__(self):

        return 'Book({}, {}, {})'.format(self.author, self.title, self.book_id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.title == other.title and self.author == other.author and self.book_id == other.book_id
```

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf Yes thanks this works perfectly I'll be selecting this as best answer

Comment: If `__repr__` and `__str__` are the same, there is no reason to define both. Just `__repr__` is enough.

Comment: @SethMMorton, thank you to let me know, you are open to edit my answer if you wish